# Biostatistics vs Statistics

Tags: graduate-school

I am thinking of pursuing a degree in Biostatistics (instead of just Statistics).
I am wondering if such decision will limit my career prospect to the field of Biostatistics. Is it feasible to think that somebody with a Biostatistics degree can work as, say, a quantitative social researcher or a data miner? The reason why I am considering Biostatistics program is because I get to take an epidemiology course, which to me sounds interesting. However at the same time I don't want to limit my career prospect strictly to the field of biostatistics....

thank you :)

Comment: What do you see yourself doing 5-10 years from now?  What type of work / research do you want to get involved in?

Comment: I hope this isn't poor etiquette, but I'm going to link to my own blog here, as I wrote a longish post on this very idea: [you are NOT your college major](http://shadyacres.tumblr.com/post/21351706412/you-are-not-your-college-major). This generally applies to the higher degrees as well.

Comment: Are these degrees MRes, or are they MSc? What's your first degree in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single right answer. There is value in specialisation, and value in generalisation.

To do statistics well, domain knowledge is crucial. So, if your work is to be in, say, health epidemiology, then the more knowledge you have of how health interventions are measured, and the causal patterns, the better a statistician you can be.

On the other hand, tools developed by health epidemiologists are now being used in other fields (for example, this [energy epidemiology programme](http://energy-epidemiology.info/) that I'm involved with), so the analytic skills are portable - but you will need to pick up knowledge in any domain you move into.

Maybe you need to base your decision on whether you want the first job or two after you finish the Masters to be in biostatistics. If you study biostatistics, then you'll have some domain knowledge, your analytic skills will be best directed to the right tools, and if it's designed well, the Masters will give you some opportunity to network with potential future employers: it will have guest lecturers from such institutions, and it will have a research component that you can do in partnership with one.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you have a math background?  If so, I would say go with regular stats and see if you can gear your course of study more towards the medical side of things (by taking a course in epidemiology or other medically related courses, and doing a research project in the biomedical field).  I think you will leave more doors open this way.  I think that Biostats is generally geared more towards biomedical research.  You collaborate with doctors and scientists.  Taking statistics would allow you to go this route if you desire, but also leave doors open to the quantitative social research/data mining that you mentioned in your post.  Then again, take what I say with a grain of salt.  Do more research on each subject to find out what is best for you.